# How to overcome duplicate ID while making transactions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a live web application(.NET), in which I have a facility for making transactions. When more no. of users make any transactions at the same time, duplicate/same transaction ID gets generated for all the users who're all making transactions. Is there any way to avoid creating same ID ? I tried the following solutions but nothing helps.

```
1.Mutex
2.Table lock(SQL)
3.Generating Transaction ID at the time of inserting into the table.
```

Comment: How can we answer without seeing what you are doing to generate the transaction id? Right now, the answer to your question is: yes, there is a way to avoid creating same ID.

Comment: What database are you using?  You need to use a database that is designed for multi-users like SQL Server.  To prevent duplicate IDs in SQL server you need a stored procedure that assigns unique ID.  If you have a Group of servers then each server must assign ID so there  are not duplicates.

Comment: Yes I am using SQL only. But I want to generate the ID manually(MAX + 1) not auto-generated, because I am appending some characters to it.

Comment: That's the worst way you could do it. "SQL" doesn't mean Microsoft SQL Server, but I'm going to assume that's what you mean. You probably want to create and use a Sequence. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Use a database to generate the ID.  Some possible examples:

SQL Server has an auto increment feature.  Oracle has a sequence feature

This will ensure your ID to be unique.

You mention SQL, so you have a database accessible.

Comment: Yes I am using SQL only. But I want to generate the ID manually(MAX + 1) not auto-generated, because I am appending some characters to it.

Comment: Create a second column...create a trigger after insert to append the newly created ok info to the other data

Comment: Max is a bad idea...you'll have a problem...find a way to use auto increment

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

SQL Server already has an auto-increment feature that is both guaranteed to generate a unique ID and is efficient.

If you want to "add letters to that ID", the simplest solution is to add a separate `varchar` field that contains those letters, and then format them for display as a single number in your application (either by using a SQL query to do so or [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
ID   | IDText                                Application Display
------------------                     -----------------------
1    | MyLabel                               1-MyLabel
2    | MyLabel                               2-MyLabel
3    | FooBar                                3-FooBar
4    | SomeText                              4-SomeText
```

So, in the above, `ID` would be an auto-increment `int` field and `IDText` would be a `varchar` (or `char` if you want a fixed length).

As you can see, even if the same string such as `"MyLabel"` were added at the same time, you would get a different `ID` to append to it so you in effect have a unique ID.

### Option 2

Use a stored procedure to contain the following logic in a single transaction with [`BEGIN TRANSACTION/END TRANSACTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql):

1. Query for the highest ID
2. Add 1 to that ID
3. Create a new record with the new ID
4. Return that ID

The transaction will guarantee that the number cannot be duplicated. This is less efficient for creating IDs, but more efficient at looking them up than the 2-column approach.

Comment: how will transaction "guarantee that the number cannot be duplicated"?

Comment: This seems to repeat a common misconception regarding transactions vs locking. See for instance [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468742/is-a-single-sql-server-statement-atomic-and-consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468742/is-a-single-sql-server-statement-atomic-and-consistent)