SqlCommand causes a lock in SQL Server
I am trying to clear out a large amount of data out of a SQL Server table. In SSMS, I run this:
DECLARE @CutoffDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 10000;

-- Loop to delete dependent records in batches
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DELETE TOP (@BatchSize) FROM ChildTable
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
                 FROM ParentTable
                 WHERE LogDateTime < @CutoffDate);

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        BREAK;
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END

It's been running for hours, but in a separate session I'm able to query progress with
SELECT TOP 1 LogDateTime 
FROM ChildTable 
ORDER BY ID

But I'd like to create a job that keeps the table empty, so I put that query into a SqlCommand and executed it asynchronously.
Now, I am no longer able to check on the progress with my simple SELECT statement. It's like SqlCommand has made its own transaction and/or locks that SSMS did not.
Does anyone know what is happening?
Note: I'm not asking for a solution. I can run the query through SSMS or use a C# loop. I'm more interested in why they execute differently.

I do no know how big the parent table is but this part is selecting all IDs from the parent table : SELECT ID
FROM ParentTable
WHERE LogDateTime < @CutoffDate)
You probably need to put a top/limit on this so you do not select every ID in the table.  Or select X number into a temp table and in the IN statement use that table with the limited number of rows.

I don't understand why you use BEGIN/COMMIT TRANSACTION inside your code, since single statement is ran in transaction anyway.

Are you executing the exact same code from C# or did you replace any of the variables with parameters?

BTW you don't need the sub query you can just do DELETE T  FROM (SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) * FROM ParentTable WHERE LogDateTime < @CutoffDate) T to delete an arbitrary batch of rows meeting that criteria (or add an ORDER BY ID to the derived table if you want the batches processed in a specific order as your peek SELECT implies)

@siggemannen I can test some more, but I put it there to ensure that there was no wrapping transaction.

Also, it appears that it is not a single statement. The SELECT is separate from the DELETE. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21468742/1152054 Not that it really matters in my case.

@MartinSmith No change. I just copied and pasted it.

Also, we are getting sidetracked. The question is why they execute differently in SSMS and SqlCommand.

From what you describe, it appears that your app code is wrapping a transaction around the method call and thusly causes a huge lock. You can double-check it from SQL Server logs. A solution would be to remove the WHILE and repeatedly call this until there's nothing to be removed.

Profiler shows no signs of an outer transaction. I know how to solve the issue; I was just curious why they were behaving differently.
