# Move data from one table to another with Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-8.2

I wanted to move log datas that have a specific user_id to a new table on Redshift. I've started playing with `WITH` block [like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697453/2747638) :

```
WITH moved_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM sensor_log_enable
    USING sensor_log_disable
    WHERE sensor_log_enable.user_id
       IN (16,17,18)
    RETURNING sensor_log_enable.*
)
INSERT INTO sensor_log_disable
SELECT * FROM moved_rows;
```

But redshift doesn't like it.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELETE"
LINE 2:     DELETE FROM active_connections
```

Redshift doesn't seem to include `DELETE` in `WITH` block. What's the best strategy then ? 
1 `INSERT INTO` then an `INNER JOIN` OR `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `DELETE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'move' data between tables, you must:

- Use `INSERT INTO` to *copy* the data to the target table
- Use `DELETE` to *delete* the data from the source table

They must be performed as **separate SQL commands**. You can, however, wrap those commands in BEGIN/END statements to commit them as one transaction:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO...;
DELETE FROM...;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks John for you answer.