# Is the following compound query guaranteed to be atomic?

Tags: multithreading, postgresql

I would like to reserve a large amount of object ids prior to a complex COPY operation.  I know `setval` and `nextval` have atomic guarantees, but do these guarantees hold in a multithreaded environment if I'm using them in a compound statement such as the following?  I'm using postgresql 9.6.

```
SELECT setval('objects_id_seq', nextval('objects_id_seq') + 9999); -- returns the last reserved id
```

Comment: Specifically, is it possible for the sequence value to change between the time of the inner call of `nextval` and the outer call of `setval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know `setval` and `nextval` have atomic guarantees

Yes, but the guarantees may not be what you think they are. Remember that sequences are exempt from normal transaction boundaries. Your `setval` will take effect immediately on other concurrent transactions. It's atomic - it either happens in its entirety or not at all - but that doesn't mean it obeys all ACID properties.

Your query is *definitely* going to affect concurrent queries. Specifically, the value of the sequence will continue to increase between `nextval` and your subsequent `setval`, if there are concurrent `nextval` calls from other queries. So if your intent is "reserve 9999 IDs"  it won't work, you might actually only reserve 9989 if 10 other sessions called 'nextval' in the small window between your nextval and setval calls.

You can't `LOCK` a sequence from SQL either, so you can't just take an `EXCLUSIVE` lock on it.

You can either:

- Assign way more extra values than you need and hope you're fast enough;
- Lock the table that uses the sequence in `EXCLUSIVE` mode and hope nobody concurrently calls `nextval(...)` on the sequence directly;
- let `COPY` assign generated keys from a `DEFAULT nextval(....)` like usual;
- Assign generated keys a different way, such as a counter table, where you can apply stronger locking.

What I think you really want in this case is a `nextval` variant that increments by your supplied value e.g. 9999, not by 1. PostgresSQL doesn't have such a function yet, but it'd be really handy to have one. Patches welcome!

---

You might be thinking "what if I `ALTER SEQUENCE ... INCREMENT 9999` then call `nextval` then `ALTER SEQUENCE ... INCREMENT 1`. Yeah, don't do that. Unfortunately, `ALTER SEQUENCE`'s effects will *also* become visible outside transaction boundaries due to the same properties that make `nextval` work. So concurrent queries calling `nextval` might get a 9999-row jump too. You might not care, but it's worth knowing about. I wouldn't recommend that you rely on this behaviour.