# Node.js and Postgres: Temporary table "relation does not exist" on chained query

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm trying to create a temporary table, then execute a `SELECT` query on it using the [node-pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) library. Using promises and `.then()`, I wait for the table to be created (or it seems that should be the case), then do my selection query:

```
  const tempText = `
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS
    (
      SELECT colA, colB
      FROM foo
      GROUP BY colA, colB
    )
  `;

  const queryText = `
    SELECT colA, COUNT(colA) as total
    FROM temp1
    GROUP BY colA
    ORDER BY COUNT(colA) DESC
  `;
  // using pooling
  return db.query({ text: tempText, values })
    .then(() => {
      return db.query(queryText).then(({ rows }) => rows);
    })
    .catch((err) => { throw err; });
```

This code is all lives inside a GraphQL resolver. The trouble is, the first time I hit it via an API, I get "relation \"temp1\" does not exist", But all subsequent calls are successful and return data. Why would this be? I'm waiting for the first query to finish before doing the `SELECT`

Comment: Combine the two statements with the WITH operator as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974057/move-data-from-one-table-to-another-postgresql-edition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary tables are specific to a session, and separate `db.query()` calls aren’t guaranteed to run in the same session, since `db` is a pool that acquires a client separately for each `query()` call. Grab a client explicitly:

```
return db.connect().then(async client => {
  try {
    await client.query({ text: tempText, values });
    const result = await client.query(queryText);
    return result.rows;
  } finally {
    client.release();
  }
});
```

Note also that `.catch((err) => { throw err; })` doesn’t do anything.